# I downloaded tailwind css intellisense plugin. Auto-completion works perfectly but does not sort classes. How can I fix this any ideas?

Tags: css, tailwind-css, next.js13, prettier, tailwind-in-js

I havent found anything about it anywhere. Seems like I am the only one having this trouble...

I looked for the other opened questions about this plugin but none of them has sorting problem. I haven't found a solution. Like I said no problem auto suggestion and auto completion but does not sort classes. I was already using prettier.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the VSCode Tailwind Intellisense plugin, that does not do class sorting. If you are using Prettier, consider looking into the [Tailwind Prettier plugin](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/prettier-plugin-tailwindcss).

Comment: No I did download prettier plugin